# can't run laravel schedule from cron job didn't work in cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I have a problem when i try to run `php artisan schedule:run` from cron job

### Cron Job Command

```
php -d register_argc_argv=On /home/thgfixlp/project/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

[image]

but when i run the same command from the terminal it worked correctly

### Kernal.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $schedule->command('timeslots:clear')
     ->everyMinute()
     ->runInBackground();
}
```

Comment: the scheduler should be ran every single minute ... but what issue are you having currently?

Comment: it isn't run at all

Comment: what isn't ran at all?

Comment: the command of cron job didn't work

Comment: what tasks do you have scheduled at what frequency ... and the scheduler should be ran every minute

Comment: but if i run the command from ssh or terminal it works fine

Comment: @lagbox check the question again i add my kernal method

Comment: anything in any error logs on the server?

Comment: i found this only warning but i don't know where it comes from `[10-Nov-2020 18:20:06 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: but im the laravel logs there is no errors

Comment: @lagbox it fixed by add the full path of `php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fixed by adding the full path of `PHP`

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

after editing it would be like this

```
/usr/local/bin/php -d register_argc_argv=On /home/thgfixlp/project/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```